# Steam is "running installation script (mic)", but what for?

Tags: steam

After starting a new game, Steam says "running installation script (mic)". It takes around 5-10 seconds to finish. I know that Steam runs installation scripts for different libraries that games need, but what does this one do?
I saw it for the first time after the last Steam client update.

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of the exact message? What game are you launching?

Comment: It Risen, the other time it was Atom RPG, looks like it wont show up again until its steam client update or when i do complete win10 reinstalation (which i did yesterday). Text is located near game launch button.

Comment: Check your `.appmanifest`, it should contain references to scripts that it needs to run.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, Mic (and Ori for EA games relying on Origin) are 'headless' installation scripts that prepare the game by:

- Installing core prerequisites for the game to run, such as DRM and Anti-cheat systems like Denuvo, Punkbuster, and EAC.
- Installing system prerequisites for the game to run, such as versions of Visual C, or other programming languages or even DirectX versions depending on system configuration.
- Configuring the Registry (or system variables on Mac and Linux) for the game.
- Other specific tweaks or changes to the program or system that require the game to function.